# Write a program that read from a file and print the line with line number

Tags: bash

I need to write a program that will read line from a file and then output the lines.

So the files contains this:

```
This is the first line
This is the second line
This is the third line

This was a blank line
```

The output should be this:

```
1. This is the first line
2. This is the second line
3. This is the third line
4.
5. This was a blank line
```

I know I can do:

```
nl -b a tst16
```

But this doesn't print the "." after the numbers plus I want to know if there is a way to do this is like a loop or something.

Comment: At least in the GNU coreutils version of nl, it seems to be possible to customize the separator string in the way you want e.g. (using bash) `nl -b a -s $'.\t' tst16`

Comment: Try : `perl -ne 'print "$.. $_"' file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a short `while` construct:

```
% i=1; while IFS= read -r line; do printf '%s. %s\n' "$i" "$line"; ((i++)); done <file.txt

1. This is the first line
2. This is the second line
3. This is the third line
4. 
5. This was a blank line
```

**Expanded:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
i=1
while IFS= read -r line; do 
    printf '%s. %s\n' "$i" "$line"
    ((i++))
done <file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk it is enough to do:

```
awk ' { print NR". " $1 } ' < file.txt
```

$1 is the string of text in the input, and NR an internal awk variable that tracks the current line number (e.g. Number of Records).

[8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use nl too --

```
nl -s. -ba file
     1.This is the first line
     2.This is the second line
     3.This is the third line
     4.
     5.This was a blank line
```